# Inject.js not loading on page?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am making a really simple extension, but I am having troubles with making my inject-files actually being injected. I have a css file and a js file. None is injected. 
Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "CSGO500.COM BOT",
  "description": "The bot bets on the different colors depending on which bot you choose. Just set your bet amount as normal and start the bot. Reload page to stop bot",
  "version": "1.0",
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://csgo500.com"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Choose your desired bot",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

Any Ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: @Cornwell , it was as easy as that. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! I'll move my comment to the answers then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the matches to this: `"https://csgo500.com/*"`